# Why LinkedList clone method implementation needs to store the copyied list into virgin state?

Tags: java

```java
    public Object clone() {
        LinkedList<E> clone = superClone();

        // Put clone into "virgin" state
        clone.first = clone.last = null;
        clone.size = 0;
        clone.modCount = 0;

        // Initialize clone with our elements
        for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
            clone.add(x.item);

        return clone;
    }
```

This is the source code of `LinkedList`. The `clone` already has the elements in the original list, what is the purpose of making it empty and assigning the elements again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that a `java.util.LinkedList` is implemented, is that it uses `Node<E>` objects to link elements together. And a `LinkedList` object has a reference to the `first` and `last` `Node<E>` in the list.

If you scroll around a bit you'll find this declaration:

```
private static class Node<E> {
    E item;
    Node<E> next;
    Node<E> prev;

    Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
        this.item = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

Visually, a `LinkedList` with 4 elements can be thought of like this:

[image]

When cloning a linked list, what we would expect to happen is that the entire chain of `Node`s is copied. Like this:

[image]

However, `superClone` just calls `super.clone`, which does *not* make copies of these `Node` objects. It only copies the `LinkedList` object. Therefore, it would be incorrect to implement `LinkedList.clone` by just calling `super.clone`, because then the cloned list would use the same chain of `Node`s as the original:

[image]

This would mean that adding something in the middle of the chain would add that thing to both the cloned list, and the original list!

By resetting the cloned list to its initial state, and then re-adding all the elements from the original list, we create a new chain of `Node` objects for the cloned list. This is because `add` creates new `Node` objects:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    linkLast(e);
    return true;
}

void linkLast(E e) {
    final Node<E> l = last;
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);
    last = newNode;
    if (l == null)
        first = newNode;
    else
        l.next = newNode;
    size++;
    modCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `clone` method is returning a copy of the instance object. They correct meaning of copy is delegated to the implementor class, but main requirement is when
`object.clone() != x`, it returns **true**.

In the case of the Java `LinkedList`, it returns a shallow copy of the elements, but not a copy of the elements theirslef. In this case the `list.clone() != list`, it's still **true**, but when you check their **elements** is going to return **false** (example `list.get(0) != list.clone().get(0)`).

The purpose of the copied list is to be not linked to the original one, so you could add/insert/delete elements without modify the original list.

Example (pseudo-code):

```
original.add(1);
original.add(2);
original.size(); // 2

clonedList = original.clone();

clonedList.size(); // 2

clonedList.add(3);
clonedList.size(); //3
originalList.size(); //2
```